# Disabled the past dates in datepicker and selected only "monday"

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, datepicker

I have this datepicker in my input textbox it runs well the datepicker and the selected only too. My problem is want to disabled the past dates and only the future selected day "Monday" only . Here is my code below

```
<input type='text' name='datepicker' id='datepicker' placeholder='Date:' class='form-control'>
```

```js
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            //getDate() returns the day (0-31)
            if (date.getDay() == 1 ) {
                return [true, ''];
            }
            return [false, ''];
        }
    });
});
```

What happen to my code is that the monday is selected but the past dates is not disabled. Can someone help me figured this thing out on how can i disabled the past dates?TIA

Comment: Looks like you're using a specific date picker library and asking how to do this _with that library_, so you should say which specific library (+version) you are using.

Comment: i think the new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...
Pass `mindate=0`;

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        minDate:0,
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            //getDate() returns the day (0-31)
            if (date.getDay() == 1 ) {
                return [true, ''];
            }
            return [false, ''];
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: where will i add maxdate=0 ?

Comment: in date picker if you want future date then `minDate=0` and if you want past date then `maxDate=0`

Answer (score 0):

set `minDate : new Date,`

```
$(function() {
   $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    set minDate : new Date,
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        //getDate() returns the day (0-31)
        if (date.getDay() == 1 ) {
            return [true, ''];
        }
        return [false, ''];
    }
 });
});
```

Comment: hi some clarification this one? set minDate : new Date, without a ` above?

Comment: this is datepicker setting.Seting minDate new Date, will start date from today.